# Create thumbnails using MigraDoc or PDFsharp

Tags: pdf, pdfsharp, migradoc

We have a need to take a single PDF file, break it into separate page thumbnails, and based on user input, put together selected pages into a new PDF document.

Can someone show a quick example of how to take a single PDF document and generate a thumbnail preview of each page using either MigraDoc or PDFsharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those who read FAQ lists will know that neither PDFsharp nor MigraDoc can render PDF files.

To create thumbnails from PDF pages you have to render them.

You'll need a different library to create thumbnails.

http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpFAQ.ashx